# Which energy levels are assigned to the different orbitals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

My assumption is that the further you move from the nucleus, the higher the energy level. But does the type of the orbital (s,p etc) also play a role in it't energy level?

Comment: What makes you think there is a highest level? Why are s, p, and d relevant?

Comment: @BenCrowell As far as I know, the different orbitals have different energy levels. If an electron gains just the right amount of energy, it can make a quantum leap to a higher energy level. My question was what is the "order" of these energy levels?

Comment: Please see my answer below that shows that only the orbital quantum number matters.

Comment: Why do you make assumptions when the facts are available on the internet?

Comment: @Fraser: *If an electron gains just the right amount of energy, it can make a quantum leap to a higher energy level.* The title of your question refers to a "highest" energy level. In general, this question is very brief and unclear, and it doesn't give us enough information to understand what you're asking and why. When you're writing a question, please put in some research effort, and put some effort into writing the question clearly so that people can understand what you're thinking and what you want to know.

Comment: @Fraser Are you sure you know the definition of an energy level?

Comment: There are an infinite number of increasing negative energy levels approaching zero energy. There is no maximum but there is an upper limit.

Comment: The new version of the question (v3) looks like a duplicate of [The energy level of electrons in an atom depend on $l$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33766) so I am voting to leave this question closed.

Answer (score 1):

Hydrogen orbitals (in the simple coulomb model) have a **degeneracy** in their energies. Although the eigen states are labelled by n (principle number, you referred to as orbital), l (total orbital angular momentum) and m (projection of angular momentum along a given axis) in the form $|n, l, m\rangle $ it turns out that the *energy is a function of n alone* so that $E(n , l, m) = - 13.6/n^2 = E(n) $ for bound states at least.

The reason for part of the degeneracy is easy to see - the system is rotationally symmetric. In the quantum world this means that the generators of rotations, $\hat{L}_{I} $ for $i = 1, 2, 3$ commute with the Hamiltonian. It's an easy exercise to verify that if $\hat{H}|\Psi\rangle = E|\Psi \rangle $ then the rotated state, $\hat{L} |\Psi\rangle $ is an eigen state with *the same energy.* in other words $\hat{H}\hat{L} |\Psi\rangle = E\hat{L} |\Psi \rangle $. Thus rotating a state doesn't change its energy. If we do such a rotation then the value of $m$ changes so there must be a degeneracy with respect to $m$. On the other hand, rotations keep the length of the angular momentum, $l$ fixed, so we won't learn anything about that degeneracy yet.

The additional, "accidental" degeneracy with respect to $l$ is because of a hidden, extra symmetry (I say hidden because it is not immediately apparent if one looks at the Hamiltonian). This symmetry is the quantum version of the [Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%25E2%2580%2593Runge%25E2%2580%2593Lenz_vector&ved=2ahUKEwiH-sWixPfmAhXUBc0KHchjB1UQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0NZ33Vcp9duU-L3JY5Ulfx) that was initially discovered in clssical mechanics. The vector will be labelled as $A$. It basically shows that orbits with different values of angular momentum and $A$ (related to eccentricity) can have the same energy.

Classically $A$ is conserved. Quantum mechanically its operators commute with the Hamiltonian and crucially with the generators of rotations. Thus we can label states with their value of $|\hat{A}|$. Given a state $|n, l, m\rangle$ the action of raising and lowering operator of A change the value of $l$ to $l \pm 1$. Since A generates a symmetry these states must have the same energy and we have found the origin of the degeneracy in $l$.

Comment: You might want to make it clear that when you write *"in the simple coulomb model"* you are doing so because (a) internal magnetic effects (b) external electric or magntic fields can both break the degenercy. Discussing the scale of those effect is a further improvement.

Comment: While really true only for hydrogen, the quantum defect is very small for all orbitals with a large principal quantum number. These are Rydberg states with energies just below the ionization limit, with orbitals the size of bacteria.